# query to delete invalid mobile numbers from mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table containing 100K mobile numbers (india), but some of them are invalid mobile numbers. I want to delete all mobile numbers that are not exactly 10 digits and starts with digit less than 7.
Can you help me with an sql query for this?

Comment: Thank you friends for your support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in 2 simple deletes.

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE Length(MobileNumber) <> 10;
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE Left(MobileNumber,1) < 7;
```

Or in 1

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE Length(MobileNumber) <> 10 OR 
Left(MobileNumber,1) < 7;
```

Comment: Yes better than substr().

Comment: FYI: When you are happy with a answer you should mark it as Coorect Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here how you can check the length and start of the digit

```
mysql> select length(5234567896);
+--------------------+
| length(5234567896) |
+--------------------+
|                 10 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select substr(5234567896,1,1);
+------------------------+
| substr(5234567896,1,1) |
+------------------------+
| 5                      |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So combining above 2 query you can construct the delete query something as

```
delete from table_name 
where 
length(column_name) < 10 OR substr(column_name,1,1) < 7
```

UPDATE : From Kay Nelson's note delete if the length is not 10 meaning 9,11 etc
In that case the condition should be

```
length(column_name) <> 10
```

Comment: This will only delete numbers with less than 10 it could be the case that a phone number has 11 or more digits.

Comment: well in that case just need to change `< 10` to '<> 10'

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Numbers
WHERE LEN(TRIM(CAST(mobile_number as CHAR(50)))) != 10 
OR LEFT(LTRIM(CAST(mobile_number as CHAR(50))),1) != '7'
```